# No se aplica el estilo a Chrome usando checkbox

Tags: html, css

**Busco crear menu lateral desplegable usando el checkbox**
El menu desplegable funciona correctamente con firexfox pero no en chrome

```css
/*NORMALICE*/
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root{
 --gray_1: hsla(246, 0%, 24%, 1);
 --gray_2: hsla(246, 0%, 32%, 1);
 --gray_3: hsla(246, 0%, 40%, 1);
 --gray_4: hsla(246, 0%, 50%, 1);
 --gray_5: hsla(246, 0%, 65%, 1);
 --text-color: white;

 --size_h0: 20px;
 --size_h1: 18px;
 --size_h2: 16px;
 --size_h3: 14px;
 --size_h4: 12px;
 --size_h5: 10px;
}
body{
 /*background: whitesmoke;*/
 background: hsla(0,0%,15%,1);
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
 font-family: sans-serif;

}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,picture{
 margin: 0;
}
picture{
 /*padding: 0;*/
}
main{
 width: 100%;
}
body,h1
{
 margin: 0;
}

ul{
 list-style: none;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: whitesmoke;
}
p{
 font-size: 20px;
}
.fxc{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.fxcc{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/


@media screen and (max-width: 320px)  {
      body{
          /*background: red;*/
        }
        #main{
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
          grid-template-rows: 60px auto auto auto;
          grid-gap: 13px;

        }

        #header{
          grid-column: 1 / 13;
          display: flex;  
          justify-content: center;
          background: var(--gray_1);
          position: relative;
        }
        #section{
          grid-column: 1 / 13;
          color: white;
          background: var(--gray_2);
          padding: 14px 0px;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        #footer{
          grid-column: 1 / 13;
          color: white;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background: var(--gray_3);
        }


    .icons_header_1{
        /*Flex Center Activo # > picture*/
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;/*No Chrome*/
        cursor: pointer;

      }
    .icons_header_1 picture img{
      max-height: 60px;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .icons_header_1:hover{
      background: var(--gray_5);
    }
    
/*-----------------FUNCIONA EN FIREXFOX Y NO EN CHROME-------------------------*/

    #header section{
      background: var(--gray_3);
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      left: 0px;
      transition: all .35s;
    }
   
    #header input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #menu-caja{
      left: 500px;
    }
/*------------------------------------------*/


    #header #menu-caja label {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      transition: all .2s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #header #menu-caja article:nth-child(1):hover{
      background: var(--gray_4);
    }
    #header #menu-caja article picture{
      max-width: 70px;
      max-height: 70px;
    }
    #header #menu-caja article picture img{
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      padding: 0px 20px;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    #header #menu-caja article{
      width: 100%;
    }
    #nav{
      width: 100%;
    }
    #nav ul li a{
      width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .2s;
      padding: 15px 0px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #nav ul li a:hover{
      background: var(--gray_1);
    }


}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <header id="header" class="fxc">
   <div id="title">
    <h1>TITULO</h1>
   </div> 
      
      <!-- BOTON -->
   <input id="menu-btn_duo" type="checkbox"  style="">
   
   <div class="icons_header_1">
    <label for="menu-btn_duo">
     <picture class="fxc">
      <img src="<?php echo ICONS_IMG ?>menu-btn.png" alt="menu-btn">
     </picture>
    </label>
   </div>

   <!-- MENU DESPLEGABLE -->
   <section id="menu-caja" class="fxcc">
    <label for="menu-btn_duo">
     <article>
      <picture class="fxc">
       <img src="<?php echo ICONS_IMG ?>menu-btn-2.svg" alt="menu_salir">
      </picture>
     </article>
    </label>
    <article>
     <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
       <li class="fxcc">
        <a class="fxc" href="">INICIO</a>
        <a class="fxc" href="">NOTICIAS</a>
        <a class="fxc" href="">LOGIN</a>
        <a class="fxc" href="">REGISTRO</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </article>
   </section>
  </header>
   </main>
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no funciona? ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: y no me aplica el css en chrome y si en firexfox

Comment: Espera para editar la pregunta

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta

Comment: El CSS que tienes definido para que se aplique cuando el *checkbox* esté seleccionado no te va a funcionar jamas. Para poder definir el *left* de un elemento necesitas que dicho elemento tenga un *position*, que en tu caso no lo tiene. Si explicas lo que pretendes hacer con esa regla CSS quizás podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: EL problema era la llamada del input. Chrome tiene problema al llamar en cascada. Abajo esta una descripcion sobre el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos puedes intentar algo como lo siguiente:

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
    font: 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
}

.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
}

/**
 Oculta el checkbox para dar un mejor aspecto visual
 usaremos el label para mostrar/ocultar el menu(ul) 
*/

input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/* Click para expandir el menu */

label{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57A0D4;
    padding: 15px 20px;

    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* ul tendra  display:none por defecto */

ul{
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    display: none;
}

ul li{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #4FB9A7;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover{
    background-color: #4FB9A7;
    color: #FFF;
}

ul li a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/**
 Usando el selector (~) determinaremos un color al ser seleccionado y a su vez mostrar el menu(ul)
*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    background-color: #3D88BD;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-toggle">
  <label for="checkbox-toggle">Menu Principal</label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Opcion 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opcion 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opcion 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opcion 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Bueno partiendo de tu codigo decidí darle un mejor aspecto, ocultando por defecto el **checkbox** y usando el **label** como medio de acción para mostrar/ocultar el menu(ul).

Tambien se agrega algo de color de fondo al estar seleccionado el checkbox mediante el **selector**(~).

Sin mas pruebalo y comentame lo he testeado en **Firefox** y **Chrome** sin problemas, espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Gracias. Problema solucionado

Answer (score 0):

*El problema estubo al llamar con #header y luego al input; esto indica que chrome tiene problemas al identificar ese tipo de llamada en cascadas*

```css
/* FUNCIONA SOLO EN FIREXFOX */
#header input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #menu-caja{
      left: 500px;
    }
   
/* FUNCIONA EN FIREXFOX Y CHROME */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #menu-caja{
      left: 500px;
}
```